# How refresh my list after a delete using promise

Tags: angular, promise, fetch

In my Angular app I want to update a list after a delete, but I don't know how to with promise

```
  delete(id: any) {
    this.missionService.deleteMission(id);
    // .then((res) => {
    //   this.missionsArray$[id] = null;
    //   this.missionsArray$ = this.getAllMissions();
    // }).catch((error) => {
    //   console.log('error', error);
    // });
  }
```

I tried with commented code, it work but that double my list with same datas (without deleted item)

I use this function to build my list:

```
  getAllMissions(): any {

    this.missionService.readAllMissions().then(response => {

      response.forEach(mission => {
        if (mission.data.missionCreator === this._auth.user.id) {
          mission.data.id = mission.ref['@ref'].id;
          this.missionsArray$.push(mission.data);
        } else {
          this.missionsArray$ = [];
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

and this function to delete one item:

```
  delete(id: any) {
    this.missionService.deleteMission(id);
    // .then((res) => {
    //   this.missionsArray$[id] = null;
    //   this.missionsArray$ = this.getAllMissions();
    // }).catch((error) => {
    //   console.log('error', error);
    // });
  }
```

I tried with commented code, it work but that double my list with same data (without deleted item)

Can you explain me how to have a decent refresh using promise please ?

Comment: Use strong return types in your functions and maybe some async+await

Comment: Your `getAllMissions()` does not return a list, it mutates the existing one.

Comment: Do you need to reload the list of missions when deleting an item or simply delete the item without full reloading?

Comment: what does your getAllMissions return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Empty the array `this.missionsArray$ = []` before reloading it.

```
delete(id: any) {
    this.missionService.deleteMission(id);
     .then((res) => {
       this.missionsArray$[id] = null;
       this.missionsArray$ = []
       this.getAllMissions();
     }).catch((error) => {
       console.log('error', error);
     });
  }
```

Or you can `splice` the existing array

```
delete(id: any) {
    this.missionService.deleteMission(id);
     .then((res) => {
      this.missionsArray$[id] = null;
      for (var i = 0; i < this.missionsArray$.length; i++) {
        if (this.missionsArray$[i].id == id) {
          this.missionsArray$.splice(i, 1)
        }
      }
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log('error', error);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks you for helping : )

Answer (score 0):

You can do very simple way by recalling the **`getAllMissions()`** after deleting the item.

```
delete(id: any) {
    this.missionService.deleteMission(id);
     .then((res) => {
        this.getAllMissions() //added line
     }).catch((error) => {
       console.log('error', error);
     });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you are getting replicated records since you are pushing again in the same array without resetting it. So either :

```
getAllMissions(): any {
   this.missionsArray$ = []; \\ Reset here before pushing again into same array 
    this.missionService.readAllMissions().then(response => {

      response.forEach(mission => {
        if (mission.data.missionCreator === this._auth.user.id) {
          mission.data.id = mission.ref['@ref'].id;
          this.missionsArray$.push(mission.data);
        } else {
        \\ This is not correct, since for any mission which will not have "missionCreator" matching "this._auth.user.id", 
        \\ your complete array will be flushed, if this is intended then fine
          this.missionsArray$ = []; 
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

Or You can use :

Array​.prototype​.filter() method to filter the deleted records, after your delete operation, **which will also save your 1 unnecessary api call - getAllMission**, since you are simply deleting the record which can be filtered out on client-side itself, and simply fetch all the records on pageload or with any other operations.